# How to pass JVM args to the Groovy Ant task?

Tags: groovy, ant, jvm-arguments

I have to use [this](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_the_groovy_ant_task) Ant task, but I would also need to pass in some JVM level arguments to the groovy runtime. I tried doing it the `<java>` way:

```
<groovy src="..." failonerror="true">
    <classpath>
        ...
    </classpath>
    <arg ... />
    <jvmarg value="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom"/>
</groovy>
```

But this seems to have no effect. The documentation does not mention anything related to this topic either.

Comment: you should add `fork="true"` to the `groovy` element

Comment: I got errors that I am missing the GROOVY_HOME variable when I enabled forking. However, your comment gave me a hint to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `<groovy>` task runs in the same JVM as Ant, so one should either fork it (as comments suggested on the OP), or one can set the desired JVM args to Ant's JVM itself.

Once I added the respective Java options to the command line of Ant, it worked!